# Does Path support editing of dependent picklist field?

Tags: lightning, picklist, dependent-picklist, pathassistant

I've added a dependent picklist field to Path's key fields. However, it displays only the current value and --None--.

Sub-Stage field when edited in the path:
[image]

Sub-stage field when edited from Opportunity Details page:
[image]

Comment: have you checked record types and available values? This use-case is supported as you have outlined for standard Opportunity Path.

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_sales_features_core_path_dependent_picklists.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported as mentioned by krigi in the comments.

A pop-up window will appear if there is any dependencies in the path
[image]

If you are looking to edit depended field in the Path's Key Fields area, the controlling field has to be added as well.

[image]